# Rails Active Admin - New Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to implement a new action in active admin.
I have an index for all my Orders and a need a page for CANCELED ORDERS.

I would be exactly like ORDERS INDEX page, but with a different status.

Is it possibel to do something like this?

```
index do
  column ...
  column ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scopes in Active Admin. You could do something like:

```
scope :all
scope :cancelled_orders, :default => true
```

And define your `:cancelled_orders` scope in your `Order` model.

It might be something like:

```
scope :cancelled_orders, where(cancelled: true)
```

This way you can switch between the `all` and `cancelled_orders` views, and the `cancelled_orders` will load by default. If you don't need the `all` view, you can remove the scope from admin.

Comment: Ok @Deyan.
But I need to know how to create a action for active admin, like INDEX, SHOW...